# Expo-google-app-auth gives error while signing in

Tags: android, node.js, expo, emulation, google-authentication

I'm making an app in react native and really need to add google auth. But I can't get it to work. It shows an error: `ExpoAppAuth.Get Auth: Encountered exception when trying to start auth request: null`

### Code

##### My Sign-In function

```
signInAsync = async () => {
        try {
          const conf = {
            androidClientId: config.google_client_id,
          }
          let result = await Google.logInAsync(conf);
          if (result.type === 'success') {
            console.log(result.accessToken);
            this.props.navigation.navigate('dashboard');
          } else {
            return { cancelled: true };
          }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
            return { error: true };
        }
      };
```

### Versions

- windows 10.0.19043.1466
- node.js v16.13.1
- npm 8.1.2
- expo-google-app-auth ~9.0.0
- expo 5.0.3
- Android studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1
- Emulator Pixel 5 api 30
- Android 11.0